# I'm experiencing the following log in my docker containers while putting together a django web app:ERROR: cannot drop the currently open database

Tags: postgresql, docker

Have been experiencing issues connecting to the ports based on my log entries but I have assured that my ports in postgres are assigned properly and restarted my workspace repeatedly, clearing all volumes and images as to better understand the nature of my issue but am still being met with the following log entry consistently. (Apologies for lack of detail in advance as this is my first time posting instead of reading here)

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=nc_tutorials_db
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=admin123
      - DB_HOST=pg
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE=postgres
    depends_on:
      - pg
  pg:
      container_name: pg_container
      image: postgres:13.2-alpine
      restart: always
      environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin123
          POSTGRES_DB: nc_tutorials_db
          POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      ports:
          - "5432:5432"
      volumes:
          - ./data:/data
          - ./data/misc/django_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-django-init.sql
  pgadmin:
      container_name: pgadmin_container
      image: dpage/pgadmin4:5.2
      restart: always
      environment:
          PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@example.com
          PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin123
          PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5433
          PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: "False"
          PGADMIN_CONFIG_MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED: "False"
      ports:
          - "5433:5433"
      depends_on:
          - pg
```

```
2023-04-21 08:51:07 sh: locale: not found
2023-04-21 08:51:07 2023-04-21 12:51:07.859 UTC [31] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
2023-04-21 08:51:09 initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
2023-04-21 08:51:09 You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
2023-04-21 08:51:09 --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
2023-04-21 08:51:09 psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-django-init.sql:1: ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
2023-04-21 08:51:10 2023-04-21 12:51:10.334 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit
2023-04-21 08:51:10 2023-04-21 12:51:10.334 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-04-21 08:51:10 2023-04-21 12:51:10.334 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-04-21 08:51:10 2023-04-21 12:51:10.341 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-04-21 08:51:10 2023-04-21 12:51:10.351 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-04-21 12:51:09 UTC
2023-04-21 08:51:11 2023-04-21 12:51:11.185 UTC [22] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2023-04-21 08:51:12 2023-04-21 12:51:12.099 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2023-04-21 08:51:12 2023-04-21 12:51:12.103 UTC [21] LOG:  redo starts at 0/15D5188
2023-04-21 08:51:07 The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
2023-04-21 08:51:07 This user must also own the server process.
2023-04-21 08:51:07 
2023-04-21 08:51:07 The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2023-04-21 08:51:07 The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2023-04-21 08:51:07 The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2023-04-21 08:51:07 
2023-04-21 08:51:07 Data page checksums are disabled.
2023-04-21 08:51:07 
2023-04-21 08:51:07 fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
2023-04-21 08:51:07 creating subdirectories ... ok
2023-04-21 08:51:07 selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
2023-04-21 08:51:07 selecting default max_connections ... 100
2023-04-21 08:51:07 selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
2023-04-21 08:51:07 selecting default time zone ... UTC
2023-04-21 08:51:07 creating configuration files ... ok
2023-04-21 08:51:07 running bootstrap script ... ok
2023-04-21 08:51:08 performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
2023-04-21 08:51:09 syncing data to disk ... ok
2023-04-21 08:51:09 
2023-04-21 08:51:09 
2023-04-21 08:51:09 Success. You can now start the database server using:
2023-04-21 08:51:09 
2023-04-21 08:51:09     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
2023-04-21 08:51:09 
2023-04-21 08:51:09 waiting for server to start....2023-04-21 12:51:09.047 UTC [36] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit
2023-04-21 08:51:09 2023-04-21 12:51:09.050 UTC [36] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-04-21 08:51:09 2023-04-21 12:51:09.059 UTC [37] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-04-21 12:51:08 UTC
2023-04-21 08:51:09 2023-04-21 12:51:09.064 UTC [36] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-04-21 08:51:09  done
2023-04-21 08:51:09 server started
2023-04-21 08:51:09 CREATE DATABASE
2023-04-21 08:51:09 
2023-04-21 08:51:09 
2023-04-21 08:51:09 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-django-init.sql
2023-04-21 08:51:09 2023-04-21 12:51:09.480 UTC [50] ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
2023-04-21 08:51:09 2023-04-21 12:51:09.480 UTC [50] STATEMENT:  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS nc_tutorials_db;
2023-04-21 08:51:10 
2023-04-21 08:51:10 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2023-04-21 08:51:10 
2023-04-21 08:51:12 2023-04-21 12:51:12.103 UTC [21] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/15D5280: wanted 24, got 0
2023-04-21 08:51:12 2023-04-21 12:51:12.103 UTC [21] LOG:  redo done at 0/15D5238
2023-04-21 08:51:12 2023-04-21 12:51:12.134 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I've also attached the .sql file the database is built off of in the hopes it may aid in this venture:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS nc_tutorials_db; 
CREATE DATABASE nc_tutorials_db;

\c nc_tutorials_db

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET default_tablespace = '';
SET default_with_oids = false;
```

I've reset my postgres, reinstalled all system tools and confirmed that my ports were assigned properly. The connection to django will go live, but it will return a browser error instead of a host error as expected at its current state.

Comment: " reset my postgres, reinstalled all system tools and confirmed that my ports were assigned properly" those guesses are off the mark.  Looks like what is happening is that you're specifying 'nc_tutorials_db' as the main database for postgres container, postgres creates the database automatically ("2023-04-21 08:51:09 CREATE DATABASE") and specifies that database when it connects to run your init script, and your init script is there fore connected to the database `nc_tutorials_db` when you try to drop it.  Include docker compose or docker postgres invocation please.

Comment: I have docker postgres invocated within my .yaml file. I don't know how to show you the code in any meaningful way in this format unfortunately.uyoik99

Comment: yaml is just text.  You can copy it and paste it into the question enclosed in ``` triple backticks on their own lines

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you for you continued help so far!

Answer (score 0):

##### Why what you're doing doesn't work / doesn't need to run

`POSTGRES_DB: nc_tutorials_db`. This line is going to instruct [the postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) to automatically create the `nc_tutorials_db` database, [and to use that database, if specified, when connecting via `psql`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L194) to run  `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-django-init.sql`.

So when you run

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS nc_tutorials_db; 
CREATE DATABASE nc_tutorials_db;

\c nc_tutorials_db
```

You're already connected to `nc_tutorials_db`.  It already exists. You can't drop it because it's your current database, and you haven't connected to another (and which db would you switch to? ).  The easiest solution is to remove these lines.

Now let's look at the rest of the init script, which is entirely made up of `SET` commands.  [As the `SET` doc explains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html),

> SET only affects the value used by the current session.

That session is going to end when the end of the init script is reached.  So those `SET` commands have no lasting effect.

**TL;DR:**  your entire db init script is pointless and you should just remove `1-django-init.sql` and all references to it.

##### What you *should* be doing

Typically an init script would create database tables and seed the necessary data, but [there's a caveat](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are only run if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup

This means you get one and exactly one pass to create your database tables / data in scripts within `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.  Once the postgres data directory is initialized, these scripts won't be run again.

As you develop your django app, your models will continue to evolve, and the database tables / data will have to be modified to be able to represent your evolving data.  You should be using [django migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/) to apply these migrations to your database.  These migrations run in the context of django, so they should run as part of your django container, not the db container.

Right now your django container starts with:

```
command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

You should adjust that to run migrations before the server is started.  This is a pretty common, simple, and effective way of doing migrations in django.  Last time I supported a django team, they ran `makemigrations` and committed the results iirc, and then when the django container started, `migrate` would run.

**TL;DR:** django should manage its own database schema via [django migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/).